# When creating a Teradata table, how do I add the current username to the table name

Tags: teradata, create-table

In Teradata, I want to do something like CREATE TABLE CURRENT_USER_table1 AS....

Whomever runs the code will then create tables under their own username. As not to overwrite tables from other users

Tried using CURRENT_USER, but not working

Comment: To dynamically specify the table name, you'll need to call a Stored Procedure. You can use SQL SECURITY INVOKER so the SP won't do anything that the caller isn't allowed to do. Does the table need to be persistent? If it only needs to exist for the life of the session, look at using Volatile or Global Temporary tables instead.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you, it does need to be persistent. So I need to create a SP with the username in it (like a variable), then use that SP in the table name?

Comment: In the SP you can use a string expression to build a DDL statement, and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run it.

Comment: REPLACE  PROCEDURE dynamic_table (my_table VARCHAR(30), my_database VARCHAR(30))    BEGIN    CALL DBC.SysExecSQL('CREATE TABLE ' || my_database ||'.' || my_table);    Then     CALL dynamic_table (work1,tble1_test)     Tried this, but still wont create a table. Trying to at least create a table first, then can see to enter the user info. Thanks

Comment: Add SQL SECURITY INVOKER clause before the BEGIN, and make the string valid DDL e.g. needs at least one column 'CREATE TABLE '||my_database||'.'||my_table||'(id int)' - if that doesn't work post the error.

Comment: The SP gets created, thank you for that. When I run the CALL dynamic_table(tbl1, work1) it gives me the error WORK1.dymanic_table.tbl1 does not exist. The database is work1, its a sandbox.

Comment: I figured it out. I did not DECLARE the sql string variable. So now I can BEGIN, DECLARE the variable, run the string with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Works